# After docker compose build web application didnt work

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose

I'm starting with creating docker-compose.yml files.
I have write project in PHP in laravel.
This is my folders structure.

```
.
├── app
│   ├── Console
│   ├── Exceptions
│   ├── Http
│   │   ├── Controllers
│   │   │   └── Auth
│   │   └── Middleware
│   ├── Models
│   └── Providers
├── bootstrap
│   └── cache
├── config
│   ├── php
│   │   └── php.ini
│   └── vhosts
├── data
│   └── mysql
│       ├── mysql [error opening dir]
│       ├── performance_schema [error opening dir]
│       └── sys [error opening dir]
├── database
│   ├── factories
│   ├── migrations
│   └── seeds
├── docker
│   ├── mysql
│   └── webserver
├── logs
│   ├── apache2
│   └── mysql
├── public
│   └── files
│       ├── js
│       └── styles
├── resources
│   ├── js
│   ├── lang
│   │   └── en
│   ├── sass
│   └── views
│       ├── auth
│       │   └── passwords
│       ├── layouts
│       ├── messages
│       ├── navigation
│       └── users
├── routes
├── storage
│   ├── app
│   │   └── public
│   ├── framework
│   │   ├── cache
│   │   │   └── data
│   │   ├── sessions
│   │   ├── testing
│   │   └── views
│   └── logs
└── tests
    ├── Feature
    └── Unit
```

I found some tutorials and write my docker-compose.yml.

```
version: "3"

services:
  webserver:
    build: 
      context: ./docker/webserver
    container_name: 'webserver'
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    links: 
      - mysql
    volumes: 
      - ${DOCUMENT_ROOT-./public}:/var/www/html
      - ${PHP_INI-./config/php/php.ini}:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      - ${VHOSTS_DIR-./config/vhosts}:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - ${LOG_DIR-./logs/apache2}:/var/log/apache2
  mysql:
    build: ./docker/mysql
    container_name: 'mysql'
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes: 
      - ${MYSQL_DATA_DIR-./data/mysql}:/var/lib/mysql
      - ${MYSQL_LOG_DIR-./logs/mysql}:/var/log/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: tiger
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mysql
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: user
    command: --innodb-use-native-aio=0
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: 'phpmyadmin'
    links:
      - mysql
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      PMA_PORT: 3306
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    volumes: 
      - /sessions
```

Line `command: --innodb-use-native-aio=0` fix error with using MySQL 5.7 image.
Also docker folder have two Dockerfiles.
One have myslq:

```
FROM mysql:5.7.22
```

Second have apache configuration(this is just coopied):

```
FROM php:7.1.20-apache

RUN apt-get -y update --fix-missing
RUN apt-get upgrade -y

# Install useful tools
RUN apt-get -y install apt-utils nano wget dialog

# Install important libraries
RUN apt-get -y install --fix-missing apt-utils build-essential git curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev zip

# Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Install xdebug
RUN pecl install xdebug-2.5.0
RUN docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

# Other PHP7 Extensions

RUN apt-get -y install libmcrypt-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install mcrypt

RUN apt-get -y install libsqlite3-dev libsqlite3-0 mysql-client
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql 
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_sqlite
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli

RUN docker-php-ext-install curl
RUN docker-php-ext-install tokenizer
RUN docker-php-ext-install json

RUN apt-get -y install zlib1g-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip

RUN apt-get -y install libicu-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) intl

RUN docker-php-ext-install mbstring

RUN apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ 
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

# Enable apache modules
RUN a2enmod rewrite headers
```

Whend i build it and start I have only message `AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.24.0.4. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message`. My database and phpadmin works, but when I want see site of apllication I see

```
Warning: require(/var/www/html/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/index.php on line 24
```

and

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /var/www/html/index.php on line 24
```

I know that apache server will evoke application in `- ${DOCUMENT_ROOT-./public}:/var/www/html` but I don't know what exactly dir form my pc write in this command.

Comment: heres a ready to rock lamp stack. give this a try, then tweak with your own settings https://github.com/delboy1978uk/lamp

Comment: @delboy1978uk I would have thought it's best to fix the problem rather than changing the configuration.  Also working with a LAMP stack is (IMHO) a bit of a backwards step rather than splitting the services out as they are currently doing.

Comment: Nigel, the LAMP stack in question is just a docker-compose setup with the services separated, just like you said. A stack is merely a name for the bunch of technologies used in your application

Answer (score 0):

1. Run `docker-compose build` and make sure it runs without error
2. run `docker ps` and find the correct container (below is my running containers and mine is  `star_apigateway_1`)

[image]

3. run `docker exec -it star_apigateway_1 bash` and enter
4. when you `ls` inside directory you must able to see all Laravel directory (as below)
   [image]
5. Inside it run `composer install` and `composer update` will solve the issue(make sure composer is installed) use below command if the composer is not there

in `dev.dockerfile`

```
RUN apt-get install -y curl nano && \
    curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

Comment: To see my project directory i changed
`${DOCUMENT_ROOT-./}:/var/www/html`
but now I have error 
`Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource. Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 80`
And ofcourse I get into the container and make composer instructions